# Getting error Alpine Expression Error: e is undefined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I integrated tiptap editor in livewire 2 and it was working fine until i upgraded my project to livewire 3.

Below is the code for Livewire Article component

```
public function insertMedia(Media $media): void
    {
        $this->dispatch('tiptap-insert-media', [
            'type' => $media->mime_type,
            'url' => '/storage/' . $media->getPathRelativeToRoot(),
            'alt' => $media->name,
        ]);

        $this->showMediaModal = false;
    }
```

In tiptap.js

```
insertMedia(type, url, alt) {
                if (type.startsWith('image')) {
                    editor.chain().focus().setImage({src: url, alt: alt}).run();
                }
                if (type.startsWith('video')) {
                    editor.chain().focus().insertContent(`<video src="${url}"></video>`).run();
                }
            },
```

In tiptap.blade.php

```
<div
    wire:ignore
    x-data="setupEditor(@entangle($attributes->wire('model')){{ $attributes->wire('model')->hasModifier('defer') ? '': '.defer' }})"
    x-init="() => init($refs.element)"
    x-on:tiptap-insert-media.window="insertMedia($event.detail.type, $event.detail.url, $event.detail.alt)"
    {{ $attributes->whereDoesntStartWith('wire:model') }}
>
```

I'm getting error at this line -

```
x-on:tiptap-insert-media.window="insertMedia($event.detail.type, $event.detail.url, $event.detail.alt)"
```

Error is

Alpine Expression Error: e is undefined

Expression: "insertMedia($event.detail.type, $event.detail.url, $event.detail.alt)"

It is being rendered like this

```
<div wire:ignore="" x-data="setupEditor(window.Livewire.find('8lIbGsfwbm2bmzfgHfIq').entangle('article.content').defer)" x-init="() => init($refs.element)" x-on:tiptap-insert-media.window="insertMedia($event.detail.type, $event.detail.url, $event.detail.alt)" wire:target="save" wire:loading.delay.class="opacity-50" style="height: 500px;overflow: auto;">
```

It was working perfectly fine in livewire v2 but not working in v3. i've tried all the option even tested if the function is passing the type, url and alt.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was this. Earlier in v2 we use to pass like type => 'test'

```
$this->dispatch('tiptap-insert-media', [
            'type' => $media->mime_type,
            'url' => '/storage/' . $media->getPathRelativeToRoot(),
            'alt' => $media->name,
]);
```

Correct way. In v3 we can pass type: $media->mime_type,

```
  $this->dispatch('tiptap-insert-media',
        type: $media->mime_type,
        url: '/storage/' . $media->getPathRelativeToRoot(),
        alt: $media->name
    );
```